# Java, SimpleXML with different prefixes in one Path

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, simple-framework

I have a XML file which has that kind of structure:

```
<a:root>
    <a:body>
      <b:do_action>
        <b:do_input>
           <request>
              <!-- There are a lot of primitive elements -->
           </request>
        </b:do_input>
      </b:do_action>
    </a:body>
</a:root>
```

I'm trying to parse this XML by using `SimpleXML`:

```
public class Request {
   // There are a lot of defined primitive elements
}

@Root(name = "root")
@Namespace(prefix = "a")
public class Root {

   @Path("a:body/b:do_action/b:do_input")
   @Element(name = "request")
   public Request request;
}
```

When I instantiate my object and want to show it as string, I get this error message:

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Namespace prefix 'b' in class Request is not in scope
```

How to deal with paths, which have different prefixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use two different namespaces, you should declare both of them:

```
@Root(name = "root")
@NamespaceList({
    @Namespace(prefix = "a" , reference="ref_a"), 
    @Namespace(prefix = "b", reference="ref_b")})
public class Root {
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have removed all `@Namespace()` annotations in my code then added `@NamespaceList` at top of my class. When I launched it, now I it throws me error: `Namespace prefix 'a' in class Request is not in scope`

Comment: Do you specify  'reference' attribute at least for one of the namespaces? Note that this attribute is an URI to give each namespace a unique name, so you shouldn't leave empty both of them.